# are the vectors obtained from PCA of a non-negative matrix always non-negative?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, statistical-inference, computational-mathematics

I'm curious as to whether this is the case, and whether knowing this fact can help us develop better "PCA analogues".

By vectors, I mean the [weight vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis#First_component) obtained from PCA.

Comment: What vectors do you mean?

Comment: @SantanaAfton Just answered in the edit!

Comment: The PCA is obtained using the SVD which is generated with Gram-Schmidt. There are no constraints that the vectors be non-negative. Non-negative matrix decomposition is obtained with convex optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your weight vectors seem to be eigenvectors of a psd matrix, and will hence be orthogonal, and so some of the coefficients of some of them must be negative.

For example, suppose your matrix was $\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}$, whose transposed eigen vectors are $(1,1)/\sqrt 2$ and $(1,-1)/\sqrt 2$. The main point is that the eigenvectors are orthogonal and non-zero.  So their dot product is zero, which typically means there was cancellation of positive and negative numbers in forming the dot product.

Comment: If I may make a request: Could you provide me with a minimal example of such a matrix and the corresponding PCA?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the example :)